# Why does the Collector-Emitter voltage need to be ≥ 0.3 V?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I have been going over transistors in class lately and one of the "rules" is that the transistor needs minimum voltage drop between C and E ie, V<sub>CE</sub> ≥ 0.3 V.

However, no derivation or much explanation was provided to understand why this is true. I have searched in some sites for this as well but haven't found an explanation. Is there something I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are designing a transistor circuit to switch and to have low losses you would like Vce to be as low as possible. You would like the transistor to be well into saturation. For a relatively low current single silicon transistor something like 300mV is a reasonable measure of it being well into saturation.

For example, consider the [2N4401](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/2N4401(TO-92).pdf), a common NPN TO-92 transistor. Here is the **typical** behavior in saturation:

[image]

As you can see Vce(sat) of 300mV covers the useful range of the transistor.

You could equally well pick 100mV for collector currents of less than 100mA, it's just a reasonable choice based on how real transistors behave.

Neither may be realistic for power transistors. Here is the similar graph for the 15A [2N3055](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/2N3055A-D.PDF):

[image]

As you can see, even at 10A and a forced beta of 10, you'd be lucky to get under a few volts Vce.

Answer (score 0):

The collector-emitter voltage is the sum of the collector-base voltage and the base-emitter voltage.
$$V_{CE}=V_{CB}+V_{BE}$$
To get an appreciable current through the transistor in forward active mode of an Si npn-transistor, the forward bias of the emitter-base pn junction \$V_{BE}\$ has to be large enough (positive) to produce an appreciable emitter-collector transistor current.
You can consider this to be $$V_{BE}\geq0.3V$$ In forward active mode of the transistor the collector-base pn junction has to be reverse biased thus the collector-base voltage has to be \$V_{CB}≥0V\$
From this follows that in forward active mode the collector-emitter voltage should fulfill $$V_{CE}=V_{CB}+V_{BE}\geq0.3V$$

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. The collector voltage can be below the base voltage; and the typical Vbe needed to turn on a silicon transistor is about 0.6 V.

Comment: @Floris- You are right that the usual turn-on $V_{BE}$ of an Si npn-transistor is more often chosen to be $0.6V$. The value for a turn-on voltage in an exponential $I-V$ is, however, rather arbitrary, just like the infamous "knee voltage" of a pn-diode. But you are not correct that in the forward active mode of an npn bipolar transistor the collector-emitter voltage can be smaller than the base-emitter voltage, it has to be larger than $V_{BE}$ i.e., $V_{CB}≧0$. See, e.g., Chapter 5.2.3 Modes of Operation, S.M Sze, "Semiconductor Devices: Physics and Technology$, John Wiley %Sons, Inc, 2002

Comment: Did you see the circuit simulation in my answer? It clearly shows the collector voltage can be below the base voltage. I guess the difference is "forward active mode" vs "saturation mode". Since the original question did not specify what mode the transistor is in, I am assuming the transistor goes all the way to saturation.

Comment: I saw your circuit simulation only after my comment. Your reasoning there seems plausible for the on-state of a Si npn switching transistor, which is in saturation mode, where the collector-base voltage is negative. In forward active mode the collector-base voltage has to be positive. It would be interesting in what context the OP found this $0.3V$ minimum collector-emitter voltage limit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple transistor circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBOdK8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I run the DC simulator, I get the following values:

[image]Vb =

As you can see, the collector voltage is about 134 mV - well *below* the base voltage, which is 702 mV (and less than your "rule of thumb" of 0.3 V).

The transistor starts to conduct when there is significant current flowing in the BE junction - because that is a (si) junction, this happens at around 0.6 V.  The relationship is exponential - so the change in voltage needed to double the current is quite small.

Now when the collector is pulled towards the emitter, the BC junction starts to be forward biased: once that happens, it will "steal" current from the base, and less current is available to flow in the BE junction.  For this reason, the collector can be pulled *some way* below the base, but not too much. And 0.3 V (which is half of the nominal 0.6 V bias of the BE junction) is a reasonable rule of thumb.

As the above simulation shows, the actual values you get will vary a bit from transistor to transistor - the 2N3904 is considered a "switching" transistor with low Vce, but other transistors may have higher values.

Comment: When using the npn-transistor as a switch, the "on-state" can be in saturation mode, i.e., the collector-base voltage is negative (forward bias) causing a current opposing the on-current. In the on-state of a switch, for a low switch resistance, it is desirable to have a high collector current and a low collector-emitter voltage close to zero. In the active (normal) mode of a npn-transistor for amplification the collector-base voltage has to be positive

Comment: @freecharly - I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

For linearity (low distortion amplification), look at this plot:
[image]

If you operate at very low currents, your linear region includes Vce < 0.5v.
At higher currents (needed for speedy response), your linear region starts at 1 volt or even higher on Vce.

Now.....what will Vbe be, for very low currents? for high currents?

Assume Vbe is 0.7 volts for Ie = 1.0mA.

Then Vbe will be 0.7v - (3*0.060v) = 0.7 - 0.18 = 0.52 volt for Ie = 1.0uA.

And Vbe will be 0.52v - (3*0.060v) = 0.52 - 0.18 = 0.34 volt for Ie = 1.0nanoA.

And Vbe will be 0.34v - (3*0.060v) = 0.34 - 0.18 = 0.16 volt for Ie = 1.0 picoA.